# Database on Android

Tags: android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Where does Android emulator store SQLite database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1510840/where-does-android-emulator-store-sqlite-database)

I am doing database application in android.i need to know where the data base is store,whether in Emulator or in our application.

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Not sure what you're asking. Could you clarify?

Answer (score 0):

The databases are stored as SQLite files in **/data/data/PACKAGE/databases/DATABASEFILE** where:

- **PACKAGE** is the package declared in the AndroidManifest.xml (tag "manifest", attribute "package")
- **DATABASEFILE** is the name passed when you call the SQLiteOpenHelper constructor as explained here: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#db

You can see (copy from/to filesystem) the database file in the emulator selecting **DDMS perspective**, in the File Explorer tab.

Comment: How to delete the database file?...

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3916740/how-to-upgrade-sqlite-database-file/3917336#3917336 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2270927/delete-a-file-from-android-application/2272533#2272533